# сортировка в цикле for in (js)

Tags: javascript, html

столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть объект с датами(`dates`), через цикл `for (date in dates)` я должен по ним пробежаться, но почему-то даты сортируются (даты с **(2)** на конце шли до цикла за обычными датами) но в цикле они стали в самом конце. можно ли как то избавиться от этой сортировки?

```
dates = {
    '2009': { href: '' },
    '2009(2)': { href: '' },
    '2010': { href: '' },
    '2010(2)': { href: '' },
    '2011': { href: '' },
    '2011(2)': { href: '' },
    '2012': { href: '' },
    '2013': { href: '' },
    '2014': { href: '' },
    '2015': { href: '' },
    '2016': { href: '' },
    '2016(2)': { href: '' },
    '2017': { href: '' },
    '2018': { href: '' },
    '2019': { href: '' },
    '2020': { href: '' },
    '2021': { href: '' }
}
for (date in dates){
    console.log(date)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, костыль, но работает:

```js
const dates = {
    '2009': { href: '' },
    '2009(2)': { href: '' },
    '2010': { href: '' },
    '2010(2)': { href: '' },
    '2011': { href: '' },
    '2011(2)': { href: '' },
    '2012': { href: '' },
    '2013': { href: '' },
    '2014': { href: '' },
    '2015': { href: '' },
    '2016': { href: '' },
    '2016(2)': { href: '' },
    '2017': { href: '' },
    '2018': { href: '' },
    '2019': { href: '' },
    '2020': { href: '' },
    '2021': { href: '' }
};

const res = [];

for (date in dates) {
  res.push(date)
}

res.sort((a, b) => a.slice(0, 4) - b.slice(0, 4));

console.log('res: ', res);
```

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую в таких случаях, где очень важен порядок ключей использовать [new Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps), который гарантированно выдаст ключи и значения том же порядке, в котором были вставлены. Завтра вам может не понадобиться чтобы ключи были хоть как-то отсортированы, тогда ответ [@Listopad02](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1424768/385375) не поможет вам. Плюс не надо создавать лишних массивов и отдельно тратить время на сортировку

Код:

```js
const dates = new Map([
    ['2009', { href: '' }],
    ['2009(2)', { href: '' }],
    ['2010', { href: '' }],
    ['2010(2)', { href: '' }],
    ['2011', { href: '' }],
    ['2011(2)', { href: '' }],
    ['2012', { href: '' }],
    ['2013', { href: '' }],
    ['2014', { href: '' }],
    ['2015', { href: '' }],
    ['2016', { href: '' }],
    ['2016(2)', { href: '' }],
    ['2017', { href: '' }],
    ['2018', { href: '' }],
    ['2019', { href: '' }],
    ['2020', { href: '' }],
    ['2021', { href: '' }]
])

for (const [key, value] of dates) {
    console.log(key);
}
```